# Python Selenium Automation Script fails to find an element on the page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to write a program using Python's Selenium module that logs in to website (Wyzant.com), enters password and login and logs in to the website using my credentials. While I was able to load website and input my login, I am unable to write a script that sends my password to the website.

I tried this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time 

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = Options()

# Launch the Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

# Go to the webpage
driver.get("https://www.wyzant.com/login")  

# Use the provided CSS selector to locate the input element associated with the label
username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sso_login-landing > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > input")

# Interact with the input element (for example, send keys)
username.send_keys("username")

time.sleep(5)

password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#Password")

# Interact with the password input (for example, send keys)
password_input.send_keys("password")
```

Gives me the following error:

> ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
> (Session info: chrome=118.0.5993.70)

The program inputs the username but fails to input the password. I have tried following options to find and interact with the password field but none of these options worked:

1. Using CSS Selector:

   ```
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Password")
    password_input.send_keys("YourPassword")
   ```
2. With the label element:

   ```
    label_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sso_login-landing > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > label")
    label_element.click()
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#Password")
   ```
3. Using Class:

   ```
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class_of_the_password_field")
    password_input.send_keys("YourPassword")
   ```
4. Using Tag Name:

   ```
    password_input = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
    password_input.send_keys("YourPassword")
   ```

Comment: Does it work if you send a tab key after inputting username?

Comment: The usual reason for this error is that you're searching for the wrong element.  Please show us the actual html for the desired element.